# Passing a value from child window to text field in parent window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass and insert value from child window to the **value attribute** of text field which located in parent window, and not to its **property**. I've tried all the following but no luck so far:

Child window:

```
function getFile(oImg){
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
var editPage = window.opener.document;
oSrc = oImg.src;
lastSlash = oSrc.lastIndexOf('/');
oName = oSrc.substr(lastSlash+1);
var logo = 'logo'+id, logoHolder = 'logoHolder'+id;
//window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).value = oName;
//window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).setAttribute("value", oName);
//window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).innerHTML = oName;
//window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).setValue = oName;
window.opener.document.getElementById(logoHolder).src = "templates/img/user/" + oName;
this.close()
}
```

Parent page:

`<input type="text" id="logo1" name="logo1" value="VALUE-SHOULD-BE-INSERTED-HERE" />`

The first one just display the value in the text-field but when I'm trying to save it with jquery, the value is actually empty. Any idea?

Comment: Works for me in my own test case. Can you try to rebuild your situation on jsfiddle so we can find out what’s really wrong with it?

Comment: @poke document.getElementById(logo) ... maybe logo is undefined... logo is not a string in simon's code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).value = fileName;
```

This should work—except that `logo` should be a string. Otherwise the opened child window will try to find a variable with the name `logo`, which it will probably not find.

So, do this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('logo').value = fileName;
```

---

No idea what you are doing wrong, maybe the PHP echo won’t output the correct ID? Anyway, it works fine for me. See this example:

#### parent.html

```
<input type="text" id="logo1" value="VALUE-SHOULD-BE-INSERTED-HERE" />
<script>window.open('child.html');</script>
```

#### child.html

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<script>
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var logo = 'logo' + '1';
    window.opener.document.getElementById(logo).value = 'something';
    window.close();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually logo is variable: `var logo = 'logo'+id`

Comment: Where is that placed? Unless it’s placed in the *child* window, that code will just register `window.logo` with the parent’s window. So if you want to access that, you will have to use `window.opener.logo` there too.

Comment: it's located in the child window.

Comment: Then I’d like to point back at my original comment: Can you rebuild your situation somewhere, so we can look at it ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this is now Window.postMessage(), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage for details.

Comment: This method worked really well.  It basically allows you to run anything you want on the parent (or any other) window.  Solve my immediate needs!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but maybe you can try to update via a function in the parent called by the child.

So in the parent add the function (I assume you can use jQuery, because you mentioned it in the question)

```
function UpdateValue(newVal){
     $("#logo").val(newVal); 
}
```

And call it in the child

`window.opener.UpdateValue(fileName);`

Although I would like to know why the original isn't working.  This might be a good workaround.